# How important is Haskell in 2013?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell in order to gain knowledge of Functional programming to apply to Java 8. Is Haskell a marketable skill?

Comment: Is learning to think in a new way a marketable skill?

Comment: Too broad and off topic. Maybe more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Learning Haskell, especially if you don't already know functional programming, is likely to make you a better programmer. There's at least some correlation between your ability to write good code and your chances of getting hired as a coder.

Comment: Learning any function programming language, be it Haskell, Lisp, or whatever will benefit you.  I would maybe refine your question as "How important is Functional Programming in 2013?"

Comment: Although it is hard to find a job writing Haskell, knowing Haskell often looks very favorable to employers. Cf. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html

Answer (score 11):

Haskell is used "in the real world," but in terms of "Am I likely to get a job using this?" it's on the very low end. Almost any other language you can likely name has more jobs that require it.

But in terms of learning, Haskell is a great language. It really helps you think about your programs differently. And having a good mind for application architecture *is* a very marketable skill.